# Are there any exceptions to the rule where a product of two odd functions is even?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, even-and-odd-functions

Firstly, I'm aware of the conditions that need to be satisfied for odd and even functions; $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $f(-x)=f(x)$ respectively.

I'm also aware that the product of an odd function with another odd function is an even function. In the [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Odd_Function_Times_Odd_Function_is_Even) for this, nothing is said about whether the two functions have to be the same or different.

So I will assume that the functions can both be the same (and hence say $x^3 \times x^3= x^6$ which is even, as required).

But now consider this function: $$g(x)= \frac{4x}{\pi}-\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2}=x\left(\frac4\pi-\frac{4x}{\pi^2}\right)=f_1(x)\times f_2(x)$$

here $f_1(x)=x\qquad$ (which is an odd function),

and $f_2(x)=\dfrac4\pi-\dfrac{4x}{\pi^2}\qquad$ (which is an odd function).

So does this mean that $g(x)$ is even? Well actually the function is neither odd or even according to $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $f(-x)=f(x)$.

Could someone please explain why the example I gave does not satisfy the odd times odd = even function relation?

Comment: Wait! $f_2$ is not odd! To be odd, a function needs to pass through the origin. No "exception" can be found for a proof :)

Comment: $f_2$ is strange but not odd. ;-)

Comment: But $f_2$ isn't odd. There's that constant term. $f_2(-x) = 4/\pi + 4x/\pi^2 \neq -4/\pi + 4x/\pi^2 = -f_2(x).$

Comment: So it seems like my mistake is assuming that adding or subtracting a constant to an odd function is that the overall function is still odd?

Comment: @user395550: Yes

Comment: Yes, for odd function it is always $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no exceptions for this rule.

Let 2 odd functions be $ f(x) $ and $ g(x) $

So, $ f(-x)=-f(x), g(-x)=-g(x) $

Multiplying $ f(-x) $ and $ g(-x) $ we get $ f(-x)g(-x) = (-f(x))(-(g(x))) = f(x)*g(x) $

Now you can assume $ f(x)g(x) $to be another function $ h(x) $ which is even because of the above result.

Since this result is obtained by taking any 2 general functions it must be true without any exceptions.

In your example, f2 is not an odd function. Check it again

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible since

$$f(-x)=-f(x)\quad g(-x)=-g(x)\implies fg(-x)=fg(x)$$

Note also that in your example $f_2(x)$ is not odd.